# send parameters to wcf

Tags: xcode, wcf

xcode
"http://postimg.org/image/js07p1aj7/"
 wcf code

Public Function SetData(ByVal value As String) As String Implements IService1.SetData

```
    'Return String.Format("You entered: {0}", value)
    ' Dim obj As New Valueclass
    'obj.Facebook = value.setvariable

    Return value

End Function
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: i have problem in sending paramter from xcode ro wcf code any help

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/458ybnwr7/ ------the error that appear

Comment: any help pls ,i spent more time

Comment: Please do not post the same question (http://stackoverflow.com/q/28074987/745969) twice.   Improve your original question so that people understand the problem you're having, what you've tried and where you are stuck.